# Rust (Cargo) linking problem with C ++ (CMake) - invalid CPP project target arch

Tags: c++, rust, cmake, rust-cargo, conan

I am a C++ developer and I want to learn Rust language.

The Rust project should work in cooperation with an existing project written in C++ (CMake and Conan manager).

I found an example of how to do this:
https://github.com/kathog/cargo_cmake_conan

Unfortunately, this project doesn't work for me.
Errors:

```
error: linking with `link.exe` failed: exit code: 1319
  |
  = note: "E:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.31.31103\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\link.exe" "/NOLOGO" "E:\\Projects\\cargo_cmake_conan\\target\\debug\\deps\\cargo_cmake_conan.103m0d0oo5qceqku.rcgu.o" "E:\\Projects\\cargo_cmake_conan\\target\\debug\\deps\\cargo_cmake_conan.1vgpv92qkfa563gd.rcgu.o" "E:\\Projects\\cargo_cmake_conan\\target\\debug\\deps\\cargo_cmake_conan.2ik8snn5mwamdgag.rcgu.o" "E:\\Projects\\cargo_cmake_conan\\target\\debug\\deps\\cargo_cmake_conan.2mdo6ws1qgtjq2t4.rcgu.o" "E:\\Projects\\cargo_cmake_conan\\target\\debug\\deps\\cargo_cmake_conan.4beqpjo0j7ggezr6.rcgu.o" "E:\\Projects\\cargo_cmake_conan\\target\\debug\\deps\\cargo_cmake_conan.4e3bl7yv0c25juve.rcgu.o" "E:\\Projects\\cargo_cmake_conan\\target\\debug\\deps\\cargo_cmake_conan.4v6e98a2pivauioz.rcgu.o" "E:\\Projects\\cargo_cmake_conan\\target\\debug\\deps\\cargo_cmake_conan.4v8v6hax3lg456p2.rcgu.o" "E:\\Projects\\cargo_cmake_conan\\target\\debug\\deps\\cargo_cmake_conan.50pke6nqplfdth5s.rcgu.o" "E:\\Projects\\cargo_cmake_conan\\target\\debug\\deps\\cargo_cmake_conan.5cs02h5ws23vasvh.rcgu.o" "E:\\Projects\\cargo_cmake_conan\\target\\debug\\deps\\cargo_cmake_conan.m50k5pz60cqstvz.rcgu.o" "E:\\Projects\\cargo_cmake_conan\\target\\debug\\deps\\cargo_cmake_conan.1r6tdfkuofwhrvl5.rcgu.o" "/LIBPATH:E:\\Projects\\cargo_cmake_conan\\target\\debug\\deps" "/LIBPATH:E:\\Projects\\cargo_cmake_conan\\target\\debug\\build\\cargo_cmake_conan-ae3c43dc13dd8a64\\out" "/LIBPATH:E:\\Projects\\cargo_cmake_conan\\target\\debug\\build\\cargo_cmake_conan-ae3c43dc13dd8a64\\out" "/LIBPATH:E:\\Projects\\cargo_cmake_conan\\target\\debug\\build\\cxx-61894c0d92cd12fe\\out" "/LIBPATH:E:\\Projects\\cargo_cmake_conan\\target\\debug\\build\\link-cplusplus-3cc8a465f5e91360\\out" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\trix\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "cargo-cmake-conan.lib" "regexp_pcre_lib.lib" "E:\\Projects\\cargo_cmake_conan\\target\\debug\\deps\\libcxx-754807c1d543514b.rlib" "E:\\Projects\\cargo_cmake_conan\\target\\debug\\deps\\liblink_cplusplus-c69868dc83e46a6d.rlib" "C:\\Users\\trix\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libstd-13da5b615652700a.rlib" "C:\\Users\\trix\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libpanic_unwind-a8b831d76b475a05.rlib" "C:\\Users\\trix\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\librustc_demangle-b1b7dd98d9f9a4a1.rlib" "C:\\Users\\trix\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libstd_detect-4af739ef7bf469f3.rlib" "C:\\Users\\trix\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libhashbrown-3eed3508b3703ba6.rlib" "C:\\Users\\trix\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libminiz_oxide-050ce0e104c2a309.rlib" "C:\\Users\\trix\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libadler-8b143218bffc06cf.rlib" "C:\\Users\\trix\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_alloc-2d4fc4aa13bade5c.rlib" "C:\\Users\\trix\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libunwind-310f6aa0f05a13a7.rlib" "C:\\Users\\trix\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libcfg_if-7fb7d195e12cf988.rlib" "C:\\Users\\trix\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\liblibc-4c39873e011bda7c.rlib" "C:\\Users\\trix\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\liballoc-daf862f55e1277f3.rlib" "C:\\Users\\trix\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_core-665ed95809278e59.rlib" "C:\\Users\\trix\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libcore-c2100e40c13f915d.rlib" "C:\\Users\\trix\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libcompiler_builtins-493ea9231a9eccf5.rlib" "advapi32.lib" "userenv.lib" "kernel32.lib" "ws2_32.lib" "bcrypt.lib" "msvcrt.lib" "/NXCOMPAT" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\trix\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "/OUT:E:\\Projects\\cargo_cmake_conan\\target\\debug\\deps\\cargo_cmake_conan.exe" "/OPT:REF,NOICF" "/DEBUG" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\trix\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\intrinsic.natvis" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\trix\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\liballoc.natvis" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\trix\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\libcore.natvis" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\trix\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\libstd.natvis"
  = note: Non-UTF-8 output: regexp_pcre_lib.lib(lib.obj) : error LNK2038: wykryto niezgodno\x98\x86 dla elementu \"_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL\": warto\x98\x86 \"2\" jest niezgodna z warto\x98ci\xa5 \"0\" w elemencie cargo-cmake-conan.lib(main.rs.o)\r\nregexp_pcre_lib.lib(lib.obj) : error LNK2038: wykryto niezgodno\x98\x86 dla elementu \"RuntimeLibrary\": warto\x98\x86 \"MDd_DynamicDebug\" jest niezgodna z warto\x98ci\xa5 \"MD_DynamicRelease\" w elemencie cargo-cmake-conan.lib(main.rs.o)\r\nLINK : warning LNK4098: domy\x98lna biblioteka \"MSVCRTD\" powoduje konflikt z innymi bibliotekami; u\xbeyj opcji /NODEFAULTLIB:biblioteka\r\nE:\\Projects\\cargo_cmake_conan\\target\\debug\\deps\\cargo_cmake_conan.exe : fatal error LNK1319: Liczba wykrytych niezgodno\x98ci: 2\r\n
```

As you can see, there is a problem with the target architecture of the library written in CXX (CMake).

I have tried to explicitly define the target architecture:

```
let dst = Config::new("regexp_pcre")
    .define("COMPILE_TARGET", "DESKTOP_x86_64")
    .build();
```

- OS: Windows 11
- Cargo: 1.62.0-nightly (edffc4ada 2022-04-19)
- Rustc: 1.62.0-nightly (18f314e70 2022-04-24)
- Visual studio: 2022 Community
- CMake: 3.22.1

Command "cargo build" was issued in "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022".

One line was commented out in the example project - the compiler should not be Clang:

```
//.compiler("clang++")
```

Still the same problem.
Any idea how to fix it?

#edit

I found a line that doesn't work:

```
set CARGO=\\?\C:\Users\trix\.rustup\toolchains\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\bin\cargo.exe&&
 set CARGO_BIN_NAME=cargo_cmake_conan&&
 set CARGO_CRATE_NAME=cargo_cmake_conan&&
 set CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR=E:\Projects\cargo_cmake_conan&&
 set CARGO_PKG_AUTHORS="Daniel <nerull@craftsoft.eu>"&&
 set CARGO_PKG_DESCRIPTION=""&&
 set CARGO_PKG_HOMEPAGE=""&&
 set CARGO_PKG_LICENSE=""&&
 set CARGO_PKG_LICENSE_FILE=""&&
 set CARGO_PKG_NAME=cargo_cmake_conan&&
 set CARGO_PKG_REPOSITORY=""&&
 set CARGO_PKG_VERSION=0.1.0&&
 set CARGO_PKG_VERSION_MAJOR=0&&
 set CARGO_PKG_VERSION_MINOR=1&&
 set CARGO_PKG_VERSION_PATCH=0&&
 set CARGO_PKG_VERSION_PRE=""&&
 set CARGO_PRIMARY_PACKAGE=1&&
 set OUT_DIR=E:\Projects\cargo_cmake_conan\target\release\build\cargo_cmake_conan-3f88e515ac5fc027\out&&
 set PATH="E:\Projects\cargo_cmake_conan\target\release\deps;C:\Users\trix\.rustup\toolchains\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\bin;C:\Users\trix\.cargo\bin;C:\Users\trix\.rustup\toolchains\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\bin;C:\Program Files\Oculus\Support\oculus-runtime;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;E:\Program Files\Git\cmd;E:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\trix\.cargo\bin;G:\Program Files\Conan\conan;E:\IT\emsdk;E:\IT\emsdk\node\14.18.2_64bit\bin;E:\IT\emsdk\upstream\emscripten;C:\Users\trix\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;E:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin;E:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;E:\Program Files\CMake\bin;E:\Program Files\LLVM\bin;C:\Users\trix\.dotnet\tools"&&
 rustc --crate-name cargo_cmake_conan --edition=2018 src\main.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no -C metadata=0e12905fd05363cb --out-dir E:\Projects\cargo_cmake_conan\target\release\deps -L dependency=E:\Projects\cargo_cmake_conan\target\release\deps --extern cxx=E:\Projects\cargo_cmake_conan\target\release\deps\libcxx-506cecc7e737d79e.rlib -L native=E:\Projects\cargo_cmake_conan\target\release\build\cargo_cmake_conan-3f88e515ac5fc027\out -L native=E:\Projects\cargo_cmake_conan\target\release\build\cargo_cmake_conan-3f88e515ac5fc027\out -l static=cargo-cmake-conan -l regexp_pcre_lib -L native=E:\Projects\cargo_cmake_conan\target\release\build\cxx-1453aa68af9ba060\out -L native=E:\Projects\cargo_cmake_conan\target\release\build\link-cplusplus-c5e33ac7f6a014a6\out
```

result of this command:

```
'rustc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

The PATH variable is overwritten and there is a path pointing to rustc:

```
C:\Users\trix\.rustup\toolchains\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\bin
```

When I set:

```
SET PATH="C:\Users\trix\.rustup\toolchains\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\bin"
```

rustc is recognized...

but when I set

```
SET PATH="C:\Users\trix\.rustup\toolchains\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\bin;"
```

';' at the end it was added, the rustc is not recognized...
why?

Comment: Shouldn't compile target be something like `x86_64-pc-windows-msvc`?

Comment: Maybe this rust-conan integration helps? https://github.com/Devolutions/conan-rs

Comment: I have edited the description - I have a lead